# Appearing and Disappearing extra space at bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I am building a simple page with a CSS-based collapsing menu on one side. The background for the page is a 3-stop linear gradient. At some point after putting in the collapsing menu, the page developed an extra band of blue at the bottom. It is below the `<footer>` section (there's nothing in the html below that, except the `</body>` and `</html>` tags). (This occurs in my Vivaldi browser (Chromium), and Edge, but not IceDragon (Firefox).)

If I hover over a "menuItem", it expands, and pushes the bottom of the gradient down toward the bottom edge of the browser. (The largest "menuItem" makes it *almost* disappear.) In Edge it then recovers the blue band when I stop hovering, while Vivaldi leaves it alone unless I move the cursor directly from the "menuItem"s to the "My opining:" bit.

Here's the html:

```
<body class="bkgdgradient">
<header>
<h1>Page title</h1>
<h3>tagline</h3>
</header>
<div class="layingout">
<div class="menuing">
<h4>My opining:</h4>
  <div class="menuItem">
    <h5>First Menu Category<h5>
    <ul><p style="display: none;"></p>
      <li><a href="#">link item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menuItem">
    <h5>Second Menu Category<h5>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">link item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menuItem">
    <h5>Third Menu Category<h5>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">link item 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menuItem">
    <h5>Fourth Menu Category<h5>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">link item 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menuItem">
    <h5>Fifth Menu Category<h5>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">link item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="talking">
<p>A bunch of text.</p>
<p>A bunch more text.</p>
<p>Even more text</p>
<p>Finally finished</p>
</div>
</div>
<footer>
<p>About me</p>
<p>Contact me</p>
</footer>
</body>
```

And here's the CSS (internal to the page):

```
.bkgdgradient {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#9cc3d2, #cfc4b8 30%, BurlyWood 95%);
}

header {
    background-image: url("F14 & KC135R.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 556px;
}

h1 {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-family: "Verdana", "Geneva", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.75em;
}

h3 {
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 800px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.75em;
}

h4 {
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

.layingout {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 250px 700px;
    grid-gap: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.menuing {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    color: SaddleBrown;
    text-shadow: 1px 0px Sienna;
}

.menuItem {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
}

.menuItem h5 {
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding-left: 2px;
    margin:0px;
}

.menuItem h5:hover {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-shadow: 2px 0px Sienna;
}

.menuItem ul {
    background-color: Peru;
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    line-height: 15px;
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.menuItem li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid Chocolate;
    line-height: 22px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.menuItem li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: Bisque;
}

.menuItem:hover ul {
  height: auto;
}

.talking {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

What bit had an unintended consequence in that styling? Does it have to do with making the background gradient apply to the body?
Thank you.

*Edit* One more item: In IceDragon, the `<div>` for the menu items does not expand down along with the menu; it seems to already be at the correct size to hold the expanding menus. Edge and Vivaldi expand it as necessary to contain the extra information.

*Edit* Fixed the `<ul>` close tags.

Comment: Your first step is to validate and fix your html. You aren't closing your `<ul>` tags correctly. You are using another opening tag rather than  `</ul>`.

Comment: @JonP - Yumpin' Yiminy, I messed that up somewhere! Thank you for that catch!

Answer (score 0):

```
.body{
   min-height: 100%;
}
.layingout {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 250px 700px;
    grid-gap: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 110px;
}
```

It could remove  extra space from bottom

Comment: The "margin-bottom" (by itself) pushed the footer downward and solved the problem. I've implemented both for now. Can you explain why this works, please? (And, it's not ideal, since I now have a big gap between the bottom of the menu and the footer section.)

Comment: A good answer provides an explanation to what has been done. This can be as some summary text, inline comments, or both.